# Creating one single Patch for different files in Custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, patch

I need to create a patch for the plugin files. I have made changes to different files in a custom WordPress plugin. Used the following command for creating  ".diff"  file.

```
diff -u original_file modified_file > newfile.diff
```

What I want is I need to create a patch that contains all the modified files, so that I can copy the patch to wordpress.org.

Answer (score -2):

Try with the folllowing command :

diff -p0 --dry-run modified_file < newfile.diff

hope this wont work

Comment: Actually what you meant with this @user9800609